# Children to parent relation is not set after un-marshalling

Tags: java, jpa, jersey, eclipselink

I've an Order object and within that a collection of Orderline objects.

Order:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Order implements Serializable{
.....
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
private List<Orderline> orderlineCollection;
```

Orderline:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Orderline implements Serializable{
.....
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Order order;
```

The order object gets send from a different application by XML.
At first I got an exception that order_id couldn't be null so I thought that the orderline was saved before the order object.

But after abit of searching I found out (seems to) that the relation from orderline to order is not set when it converted the xml to object. Tho Order does have the orderlines. So to fix this I now have to loop order the orderline collection and set the order.

```
for(Orderline line : order.getOrderlineCollection()){
    line.setOrder(order);
}
```

Although this fixes my problem, it doesn't feel right to do this to probably all relationships. Is this normal behavior? Should I fix this differently?

Comment: Well how do unmarshall xml to Java Objects?

Comment: that's automatic by the @XmlRootElement annotation